# Need a regex that will check if the string only consist letters a-z and numbers and underscore(_) and hyphen(-)

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will check if the string only consists of the letters a-z, numbers, underscore (`_`) and hyphen (`-`). I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
if (!preg_match('/^a-zA-Z0-9_-$/', $string)) {
  $reg_Error[] = 2;
}
```

Also, can I check the length with regex?  If not, I will just do it with PHP.

Comment: Check the length with strlen. Regex is a tool, not a hammer. :)

Answer (score 18):

You have to put your regex `/^a-zA-Z0-9_-$/` in a character class `/[...]/`.
It means you can match *any* character in the character class. You should also specify a quantifier, because `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$/` will match only one character.

Examples:
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/`  with the `+` sign you match it one or more time
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}$/` the same as above
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{10,20}$/` between 10 and 20 character long.
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{15}$/` it has to be *exactly* 15 characters long. You can use it to check the string length.

You can also use the following keyword to make your regex easy to read:
`/^[\w-]+$/` which matches a word character (including underscore, letters and digits) or a dash, one or more time.

Answer (score 7):

I would use this one:

```
/^[a-z_\-\d]+$/i
```

As to why I'm not using `\w`, the following quote, taken from [PHP PCRE Pattern Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php), should explain why **you shouldn't be using `\w` in this situation**:

> *A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". **The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place.** For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by `\w`.*

That behavior is not desirable in this case, so unless you want to worry about locale, use straight character classes instead of the `\w` shorthand.

If you want to specify a minimum length (for example 3):

```
/^[a-z_\-\d]{3,}$/i
```

If you want to specify both a minimum and maximum length (for example 2 and 5):

```
/^[a-z_\-\d]{2,5}$/i
```

Answer (score 4):

Shortest one:

> /^[\w-]+$/

Comment: The underscore is part of `\w`.

Comment: \w includes _. Note that in other locales, \w can include accented characters.

Comment: @seize if it would include accented characters in other locales, no.

Answer (score 2):

The regex should be: '^[\w\d-]+$'

Comment: To explain that: '-' is a special character inside square brackets *unless* it is the first or last character in the brackets.

Comment: `a-zA-Z_` can be replaced by `\w`, `0-9` can be replaced by `\d`

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9_` can be replaced by `\w` only.

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far correctly explain the character class /`^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$`/

You can check the length. + means "one or more of the preceding", * means zero or more of the preceding" and {2,4} means "between 2 and 4 of the preceding".

You can't specify the length has to be a prime, though. Specifying that the length has to be even is possible but non-trivial: /`^(xx){1,3}$`/ matches xx, xxxx or xxxxxx. The count here refers to the *number of pairs*, not the number of x'es